# Understanding goroutines for web API

Tags: go

Just starting out with Go and hoping to create a simple Web API. I'm looking into using Gorilla mux (http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) to handle web requests.

I'm not sure how to best use Go's concurrency options to handle the requests. Did I read somewhere that the `main` function is actually a goroutine or should I dispatch each request to a goroutine as they are received? Apologies if I'm "way off".

Comment: You don't really need routines for web services. The libraries themselves are already capable of handling request separately. You just worry about how efficient your calls are handled and the libraries will just handle the rest. The whole `net` mechanics are mostly already made to work like that. It's mainly why Go is so awesome, offering out-of-box awesomeness.

Comment: thanks - but I assume if within a handler I need to grab data from a database then this could/should be done via a goroutine?

Comment: No the better mysql libraries (or any other popular ones) also handle their calls through the same logic. You don't need to start advanced queues like you might be used to in Objective-C/C/C++ when using libraries like SQlite3. So again; just focus on the lightness of your code. The libraries are already awesome-a-fied :D

Comment: wow - sounds too good to be true ha ha

Comment: Yep! I'm pumping out tens of thousands of requests through my tiedot database on my 5 year old macbook pro. It's a relieve no matter from which language you come. You almost can't believe your code is done when your file isn't even 200 lines long. It's why I fell in love with Go :) Not one minute of worry for threading or overhead. Tweaking is also super easy in Go, where in other languages it's mostly the biggest pain in the *ss to late-optimize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Go's `http.ListenAndServe` to serve your http requests, the documentation clearly states that each incoming connection is handled by a separate goroutine for you. http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Serve
You would usually call `ListenAndServe` from your `main` function.

Gorilla mux is simply a package for more flexible routing of requests to your handlers than the `http.DefaultServeMux`. It doesn't actually handle the incoming connection or request just simply relays it to your handler.

I highly suggest you read a bit of the documentation, specifically this guide https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_3 on writing web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an answer even though I voted to close for being too broad.

Anyway, none of that is really necessary. You're over thinking it. If you haven't read this it looks like a decent tutorial; http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/

You can really just set up routes like you would with most typical rest frameworks and let the webserver/framework worry about concurrency at the request handling level. You would only employ goroutines to generate the response of a request, say if you needed to aggregate data from 10 files that are all in a folder. Contrived example, but this is where you would spin off 1 goroutine per file, aggregate all the information by reading off a channel in a non-blocking select and then return the result. You can expect all points of entry to your code are called in an asynchronous, non-blocking fashion if that makes sense...

Comment: As Rob Pike points out over and over you also need to be weary that, even tho groroutines are very cheap, you shouldn't overuse them and see the actual use of them. To be very honest; when not really doing anything bi-directional (like chatting or live feedback systems) I never use goroutines. I prefer to only use them as a last resort when casual things need some form of distribution in load (this might also include some libraries that tend to not use cpu cycles most efficiently; having them run in paralel instead of tandem).

Comment: @Allendar I did notice this blog post though that suggests using goroutines with MongoDB (which I will probably be using): http://blog.mongodb.org/post/80579086742/running-mongodb-queries-concurrently-with-go

Comment: Because NoSQL systems don't suffer that much from lock like RDBMS do. Glancing over that article quickly it seems they use the routines to spawn tasks to the database without waiting for direct confirmation. This might be handy when you don't care about the result. I mostly do stuff like that when placing orders for shops. Just tell the customer you're done and they'll get a mail when everything is processed. When the routines get's the confirmation from the payment provider it will mail the customer. This feels very fluent for the customer because the main process didn't have to wait.

Comment: @tommyd456 I didn't look at that example really but it makes sense if you have to aggregate the results of multiple queries. It only makes sense to use goroutines when the work can practically be divided, if I have to get objects from multiple collections and merge them (disregarding that its a poor use of Mongo and should probably just be using SQL) in memory then distributing some of that work might be a good use. However, these routines would be for an individual request, not at the request handler level. It's actually no different than my file example except the store is Mongo instead.